# Spring data Mongo DB wrong REST configuration

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, rest, spring-mvc

currently I am writing some small web application using Spring and Mongo DB. My problem is to display ID in RESTs. I found this solution:

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.data.rest.core.config.RepositoryRestConfiguration;
import org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.config.RepositoryRestMvcConfiguration;

import pl.rakoczy.taskmanager.model.Task;

@Configuration
public class RepositoryConfig extends
        RepositoryRestMvcConfiguration {

    @Override
    protected void configureRepositoryRestConfiguration(
            RepositoryRestConfiguration config) {
        config.exposeIdsFor(Task.class);
    }
}
```

After start application exception appears:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'repositoryExporterHandlerAdapter' defined in class path resource [pl/rakoczy/taskmanager/repository/RepositoryConfig.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.data.util.ClassTypeInformation.from(Ljava/lang/Class;)Lorg/springframework/data/util/TypeInformation;
```

I found solution to update some dependencies in gradle configuration, but I think I do have newest versions:

```
dependencies {
compile 'org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.21'

compile group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-context', version: '4.3.2.RELEASE'
compile group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-core', version: '4.3.2.RELEASE'
compile group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-beans', version: '4.3.2.RELEASE'
compile group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-web', version: '4.3.2.RELEASE'
compile group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-expression', version: '4.3.2.RELEASE'
compile group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-asm', version: '3.1.4.RELEASE'
compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-test', version: '1.4.0.RELEASE'
compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-web', version: '1.4.0.RELEASE'
compile group: 'org.springframework.data', name: 'spring-data-mongodb', version: '1.9.2.RELEASE'
compile group: 'org.springframework.data', name: 'spring-data-jpa', version: '1.10.2.RELEASE'
compile group: 'org.springframework.data', name: 'spring-data-rest-webmvc', version: '2.0.0.RELEASE'
compile group: 'org.springframework.hateoas', name: 'spring-hateoas', version: '0.16.0.RELEASE'

compile group: 'org.tinylog', name: 'tinylog', version: '1.1'

compile group: 'javax.inject', name: 'javax.inject', version: '1'

compile group: 'org.mongodb', name: 'mongo-java-driver', version: '3.3.0'

compile group: 'org.aspectj', name: 'aspectjweaver', version: '1.8.9'

compile group: 'cglib', name: 'cglib-nodep', version: '3.2.4'

testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
testCompile 'com.jayway.jsonpath:json-path'
testCompile 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
```

}

I am new at Spring, can you see any problems?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have added both Spring and Spring boot dependencies. Best way to start is to use Spring Boot dependencies and then add other dependencies as per requirement. Please check https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-mongodb/. The error you are getting is related to "org.springframework.data.util.ClassTypeInformation" class which is part of spring-data-commons jar file. Check if this jar file and its latest version is there in your deployed war file. I will again suggest you to clean up your Gradle build and keep required and latest files. For example you are using older version of spring-data-rest-webmvc.

Answer (score 0):

The error says that Spring is trying to invoke an init() method in that class, and none exists.

Consult the spring documentation here: http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/current/reference/html/#customizing-sdr.adding-sdr-to-spring-mvc-app